# Logo Pack - What should I include?

Tags: logo

What files should i put in a logo pack to give to clients? Should I put small, medium and large version of my logo as well as the vector file.

Answer (score 20):

Here is What I include:

### CMYK (High resolution)

- CMYK .ai
- CMYK .pdf
- CMYK .eps (Illustrator 8)
- CMYK .tiff (flat with clipping path)
- CMYK .psd (with transparency)

### Spot color (if applicable) (High resolution)

- Spot .ai
- Spot .pdf
- Spot .eps
- Spot .tiff (flat with clipping path)
- Spot .psd (with transparency)

### Greyscale 1 color (High resolution)

- Greyscale .ai
- Greyscale .pdf
- Greyscale .eps
- Greyscale .tiff (flat with clipping path)
- Greyscale .psd (with transparency)

### Solid 1 color (High resolution)

- Black .ai
- Black .pdf
- Black .eps
- Black .tiff (flat with clipping path)
- Black .psd (with transparency)

### RGB (low resolution)

- RGB .ai
- RGB .pdf
- RGB .eps
- RGB .svg
- RGB .jpg (500px wide)
- RGB .jpg (250px wide)
- RGB .jpg (100px wide)
- RGB .png (with transparency, 500px wide)
- RGB .png (with transparency, 250px wide)
- RGB .png (with transparency, 100px wide)
- RGB .gif (250px wide with transparency)
- RGB .psd (with transparency)
- RGB Greyscale .jpg (250px wide) (file is colorless but still in RGB format)
- RGB Solid black .jpg (250px wide)

### Usage

- A full usage guide for the logo including sizes to use, color breakouts, required spacing, incorrect usage, etc.

### Notes

These formats are broken down into two directories. Print and Web. "Print" containing the CMYK, Greyscale, Spot, and solid fortmats in high resolution and "Web" containing the low resolution RGB formats.

The jpg, png, and gif files are pretty much included *just so the client sees them*. If you don't provide a jpg many clients won't know what the other formats are for. They also want to *immediately* email the logo or throw it on Facebook and since they are familiar with jpg or png they can use those files.

EPS saved as Illustrator 8 allows for compatibility with many older third party applications, such as sign cutters and embroidery machines.

This may seem like a lot of files to include, but it really isn't. Most of these formats take 5 minutes or less to generate when a logtype is complete. That 5 minutes of time here, saves the client 4 hours or more when they try and scramble for a format they need when some vendor asks for it.

It would be nice to simply send a pdf or ai files and be done, but in my experience, that only ensures they client returns to you asking for more formats later. *My goal is to provide the client, up front, with every possible format they may need.*

Comment: Nice answer. I tend to provide more or less the same, but it *is* a lot of files and a lot of work imo. If the logo exists in perhaps 3 variations (no name, name on the side, name below for example) we get about 100 files which must be named, ordered in folders and perhaps listed in the guide. It's important to expect some hours of work with this. The time spent with this is the same for a 4 hour logo as for a 4 days logo. One thing about your list though: Isn't 500px a bit small as the largest raster image nowadays?

Comment: @Wolff I do whittle this down where possible. Educated clients may not need all the JPGs and PNGs or the GIF at all. It is a 2014 list... but still I feel 500px is fine for a *logo*. If they want larger, they have the vector files and psd. The reality is, all of these formats can be done by merely hitting "Save As" a number of times. The color breakouts all *must* be generated anyway. So really it's only 5 files at most, then saved repeatedly...

Comment: Easily *saved* yes. Can also be automated from Illustrator. But *systematizing* and *naming* still eats some time. (I don't know where I'm going with this. Just interested because I recently was surprised about how time consuming this was for me with an otherwise pretty quick logo.)

Comment: @Wolff I build in time for this stuff... knowing it's going to take an hour or so. But I am, in general, pretty quick. Typically, once the color break outs are set...  it only takes 5 minutes, if that, per color breakout.

Comment: I get the logic of everything else, but are the GIFs, TIFFs and EPS really necessary in 2021? Isn't TIFF just a raster format at the end of the day - JPG covers the "tangible for end users " part and vector formats cover the quality, so I can't see where TIFFs fall.

Comment: @HashimAziz .. for the most part **yes**. Many of the files are included for uneducated clients. I mean, let's face it, if you have the vector .ai or .pdf file you can easily generate *everything* else. Some of the formats are more about "customer service" than absolute necessity. If someone somewhere were to ask the client for a tiff, jpg, gif, eps, etc.. years from now... the client would have it. Ultimately most of the formats only take a couple seconds to save on my end and provides a larger encompassing, more complete, package. So why not?.

Comment: What seems pointless to the professional can be insurmountable to the non-professional without the Adobe subscription, basically.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the file formats/sizes suggested, a black & white, or a single color version of your logo if it is full color.

Comment: Yes, black and white is one that tends to be forgotten, but it's a nice option for your clients to have if possible.

Answer (score 1):

EPS is a relic at this point. You're better off with a PDF.

I also include PNG and jpeg (because they ask for it if I don't).

The sizes provided should be in response to requirements you've defined with your client: PowerPoint templates, internal documents, email signatures, signage printed in their stores, etc. One full size PDF will answer most of the odd ball stuff that comes up for them.

Comment: Thanks painclothes! I don't know what client it is for at this point. What size would you recommend I save the PNG and jpeg as? Also would you include a positive and negative version of the logo?

Comment: PDF is good if you know what the final output is going to be, but it is limiting for the client. If you are supplying the client with a logo generally (one they can use at will later), .EPS is better as it is still scalable. Strategically you may want to hold back on giving them the .EPS so that they will come back later when they realize they can't put the .PDF on the side of their building for example.

Comment: Why can't you put a PDF on the side of a building? It doesn't have to be raster based. Obviously, if you build the logo in Illustrator as vector, you save out a vector PDF for the client. Totally scalable, more widely compatible, and it produces a smaller file that can retain Illustrator editing or lock down editing of any type. EPS is dead.

Comment: @MonkeyTail The sizes you provide for any raster format (eg PNG) should reflect some client need. There's no standard outside of what your mark and your client need. As for positive/negative, it depends entirely on your design: If it is intended for both, provide them.

Comment: EPS should be included for the same reason a JPG and a PNG should be included: because the client might need it and be unable to create one themselves. Lets face it: anyone who needs a JPG made for them from a source they have in their hands is technically incapable. It is a massive failure to assume that there is NOT a software application in a business that was developed before PDF was commonplace. Especially reporting software.

Comment: Well, we'll agree to disagree. I have never had a client request EPS where PDF wasn't completely suitable. I *have* had clients with existing branding ask me what they're supposed to do with the EPS file their previous designer gave them. I usually convert it to PDF for them so they have a scalable file. For those lovely old reporting and labeling systems, they often ask for bmps. I never provide that by default -- it's just too scary.

Comment: I was talking with a guy at a party a few months ago about his job: he is a COBOL programmer. Perhaps he has software that supports PDF, but hey, the EPS can't hurt, especially if you can record an action for "common file export".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track. An .EPS (vector) is a must. I'd personally put .png's in there, making the background transparent. Nothing worse than having a file with a baked in white background unnecessarily.

Also, you should think about whether it is outputted for screen or print. You may want to include a CMYK and RGB versions of the .EPS file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback John. What size would you save the vectors as? Would you also include jpeg's or is it enough to include .png's files

Comment: Some graphically uneducated clients fear the unknown, meaning they might want a jpeg. I don't do a lot of logo work for clients, but including maybe a small jpeg can't hurt. I would keep the vectors smallish, as they can obviously scale to any size. Just make sure if you have any outlines they are baked in so they stay consistent when you scale the artwork.

Comment: Thanks!This may seem like a stupid question, but what sizes would you save a small, medium and large version of the logo? What's the norm?

Comment: If you are doing stock logo work, check out a site like [Graphicriver](http://graphicriver.net/)