# Object > Expand on font seems to change the weight of the font

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, logo

I am creating a logo for a client, I have two simple lines of text in Ai.

I have duplicated the logo and moved the copy below the original so I can compare the 2.

It seems that when I do Object > Expand on the copy, it seems a bit bolder.
Why would this be happening?

I will be providing the client with an .eps.
Is there any reason to expand the text vs. regular text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely the result of losing the font's hinting. If you print the two they should appear the same. You can also try exporting both to a raster format and see how the output changes.

Personally, I'd just send a PDF with fonts embedded. But I've [debated that issue enough](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12665/logo-pack-what-should-i-include/12668#comment17754_12668) for one day ;)

Comment: Thanks, I sent a version with the font not expanded, i didn't want to take any chances of it looking differently. Although when I printed them they all looked the same. Is there any reason I would want to expand the text when sending the .eps?

Comment: Not all font licenses are OK with the embedding in PDFs, unfortunately.

Comment: DA01 has a good point about he licensing issue. EPS being a legacy format (a very old one), it's best to conver to outlines.

Comment: You should definitely convert to outlines for a logo.

Comment: Just for the record: Any properly designed word mark should already be in outlines. Starting with a font is fine but no font is going to give you the best result for the letter combinations in question without modification.

Answer (score 1):

This is often due to anti-aliasing. Live text has built in hinting (as plainclothes aludes to) that controls how the characters get aliased. When you create outlines you lose that and then Illustrator just aliases the artwork like any other object.

I, personally, would never send a client a logo with live text in any format.

Comment: Thanks for that, why would you not send a logo with the fonts embedded? (is this to hide which fonts were used?)

Comment: First, I would not want ***ANY*** logo dependent upon having a font file. Second, any logo which simply contains an out-of-the-box font is, well... not designed very well.