# What applications should I use to make this into a proper logo?

Tags: vector, logo, text, software-recommendation

I am trying to design a logo for a company. Whilst using an app called: "Legend" on my iPhone, I came across a really cool design which fit my needs very well. However, the app is only for creating GIFs and so the quality is really low and it's just a picture (not the original file).

I was wondering if any of you could help me. Either help me design it or instruct me on the application to use to make one for myself.

I have attached the logo here:

[image: The Logo]

Comment: Could you please also tell me the font that is being used?

Comment: if you want help identifying the font, the website has a [guideline](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366) to be followed. Please make that a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to be using a vector application for the most part. [Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/) is a good prosumer option while [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) is the opensource option. [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/) is another option but its intended more for Interface design than the two aforementioned but it can be used for logos.

If you mean an app for mobile you could try [Adobe Illustrator Draw](http://www.adobe.com/products/draw.html) since you're on iPhone, I believe it exports at least some of the proper logo formats but I don't have an iPhone to confirm or test. You might also just do a search [Vector Drawing on iPhone](https://www.google.com/search?q=vector+drawing+on+iphone&oq=vector+drawing+on+iphone&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3150j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for other options that are in vector format instead of .GIF which is raster. (To understand the difference: [What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics))

Based on the image you posted the design should be pretty easy. Draw a rectangle, add text in desired font, use an alignment panel (all 3 of the above applications have this) to center it.

When you're ready to save I'd suggest this question as a good starting point for the correct format: [Logo Pack - What should I include?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12665/logo-pack-what-should-i-include)

If you get stuck then come back and create a new question detailing where you got stuck and what you tried.