# Where can I get a logo developed?

Tags: logo, designers, resource-recommendations

I've drawn a sketch on paper for my logo, but I have no idea how to translate that into a computer file. I'm sure the design can be improved, but it seems that the work I need done is not so much "logo design" as it is "logo development".

It seems I've done most of the design work and none of the development work.

Is there such thing as a "Graphic Developer"? Or where can I find someone who can develop my design?

I'm hesitant to hire a Graphic Designer because I don't want to pay for work that I've already done myself (I assume they'll charge me the same fee that they charge people who have no idea what they want), and I don't want work re-done that I've already done (I know what I want, so if they actually do the design work that I pay for and design a new logo, it will be different from what I want).

Comment: Many graphic designers will undertake such work. Call one, explain what you have already done, and provide them with a copy of your artwork, and ask for a quote.

Comment: @BillyKerr That reads like an answer I'd upvote :)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to find a graphic designer who will accept the job of vectorizing your drawing and nothing else. No doubt about it.

But beware that if you ask for "vectorizing of hand drawing", that's exactly what you will get. A professional graphic designer would deliver a nice clean vector file in the format of your choice. That isn't necessarily the same as a "logo". You'll need to find out what to do with that file yourself.

If you instead ask for "a logo based on my sketch", it will be more expensive, but the designer would probably: make sure that your logo has the right level of detail for any size, fix any errors in your sketch, create alternate version with and without company name, deliver rasterized files for social networks in different sizes, maybe give some guidelines on how to implement the logo and/or whatever your needs are.

So if you have a specific use for a vector file, go ahead and order one. But if you need help to implement the logo (and plan on making money doing it) it would probably be a good investment to buy some kind of "logo package" from a designer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a job board but, unless you want to do the work [yourself](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/74675/62949), you could try to find a dtp provider which will only execute your idea. Or any graphic designer who will accept that he will not spend time researching and thinking about ideas, but instead just take your idea and vectorize it. Which is normally a quicker job than a proper logo design job.

I have personally been confrunted with both situations and never had a problem when the client already had a sketch or idea, gets the job done quicker on both ends.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to pay for work that I've already done myself

Just some words about the value of an idea vs the value of the implementation.

**Scenario 1**

Do not underestimate the value of the implementation or development, as you call it.

---

We can have a good idea. "Let us make a fusion reactor to extract energy from water". That is the idea.

The implementation is several billions of dollars and some decades of work.

---

Ok, let's think about some more related to a graphic representation.

"I want a picture of a woman smiling".

If you are lucky you can get The Mona Lisa, or probably you need to lower the expectations.

---

Example of [The same idea... Diferent implementation.](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UouSkG5kg3c/maxresdefault.jpg)

---

I don't know if your idea is good, if it is solid, if it works, if it is actually a logo or you want an illustration.

You can hire a doctor to solve a health problem or go and buy some Pepto Bismol. You can hire a designer to solve a Corporate Identity problem, or only think you are solving it.

My question for you is. "What is more important, your company's image or your self-esteem or my design capabilities?"

Sometimes the main obstacle to the development of a company is this "I am solving it all" from the founders.

---

**Scenario 2**

You have a clear concept and you are open to the implementation, A designer is professional and you both can talk and develop the idea.

My little advice is, be open to what the expert you hire need to say.

---

Maybe I am wrong.