# How do you package a final logo design for a client?

Tags: logo, client-relations, file-format

I mean once the logo is already approved, what is the most professional way to send them the logo — and what formats do you include?

Comment: The answer to the second half of your question: [Logo Pack - What should I include?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/12665/52050)

Answer (score 2):

Here are few things you need to do for delivering your final file:

1- Make Sure you are sending these vector files:
EPS (Encapsulated Post Script)
AI (Adobe Illustrator File)
PSD (Photoshop)

2- Make sure your provide:
Font Link if you are using the free fonts in separate readme file
Copyright document saying that you have transferred all the rights. 
Different logo versions (Black, White) Favicon or Icon if possible.

3- Extras:
Provide 3D Mockup Preview for social profiles
Provide Layered version (Fonts + Graphics)

Comment: Those formats are fine, but most clients can't deal with them directly, so be sure to also include SVG and various Raster formats as well (ideally, you'd just ask the client what they want/need)

Comment: Yes! Agree. SVG is also an important file but, you cant compare this with vector file PSD EPS and Adobe Illustrator main version AI

Answer (score 1):

What seems the most professional way to do it, from my experience, is to present the following:

1. actual logo in editable format (ai or eps, preferable) - include a version of the icon separated from text if applicable
2. logo in non editable format (png is the best choice, as size doesn't matter). I would provide both light and dark versions of the logo (you do have them right?) in both clear and opaque background. Why? Because not all customers have Illustrator installed on their machine and they just need a logo for their email footer or something
3. a guide on logo usage in pdf format. Please include following info:

   - color swatches for main logo colors (and backgrounds if applicable)
   - positioning guides (minimum margin, minimum size etc.)
   - examples on usage for both light and dark versions, tied in to dos and don'ts
4. Font files used in the logo, if any (licensing should be present as well, if applicable)

Comment: Could you please select one answer as accepted if you feel it best answers your question? (Not necessarily mine)

Answer (score -4):

Obviously in a fancy USB stick layed in matching coloured silk in a fitting coloured, recycable box with the logo on it, and, ofcourse a letter.
For the formats just anything reasonable, also in different sizes and with transparent background

Comment: Is that what they teach in GD school these days? If meant as a sarcastic answer, please don't do it.

Comment: Oh bummer! I just burned the logo files onto a CD and printed nifty CD cover stickers with my name in WordArt. Do you think it would look unprofessional if I mailed a USB stick as well?

Comment: Not if packaged appropriately. I suggest layering the CD on Top, beneath the letter (perhaps with the advice to come forward with any File-type requests e.g.) and below that the USB-Stick