# Delivery of JPG logo files to client

Tags: logo, jpg

When providing logo files to a client, I always include AI, PDF and social media PNG. I'm not sure what to do with JPG though. What size (document size) JPG is standard to send to a client? Are specific sizes for specific uses required?

Comment: Jpgs, like pngs, are merely provided so the client sees a format they may be more familiar with. Size is up to you.

Comment: As always, ask your client.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're including accessible vector formats then the client should have the means to generate any raster versions they may need at any size. It's also worth noting that for a logo, a PNG should be usable and preferable (being lossless) to a JPG in most cases where a raster format is needed... So you're mostly handing over a JPG to keep the client happy (if you don't there's a good chance they'll either come back asking for it in the future or create one themselves at the wrong size etc.).

I generally supply a high-resolution version and a low-resolution version of raster formats. There's no set size to this but they will roughly be:

- low-resolution: 600px
- high-resolution: 2500px

That is a rough estimate and just what I do though, that's not essential or "standard".

If there are specific uses that require a JPG at certain sizes then of course you can supply those too, but that's a case-by-case thing that you need to discuss with the client (and of course there is a high chance that those cases don't actually need a JPG so that is a good time to educate your client).

For a broader view on what you should include when delivering a logo see:

[Logo Pack - What should I include?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/12665/52050)

Answer (score 1):

I do not deliver a jpg file. What I "deliver" is an explanation why I do not deliver a jpg file.

- Any application where someone would need a JPG can be replaced with a PNG file.
- No compression artifacts.
- Transparency.

It is better to help to understand your client that to encourage bad practices using wrong file formats for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Raster versions are most likely to depend on the client's immediate need, as they can always use the vector files to generate additional raster files. So, better ask the client what the JPG version is for, then you will know what size it should be. Otherwise, if no specific size is requested, just go with a general standard: put it on an A4 sheet and export at 150dpi.

Comment: A4 sheet - but _at which resolution_?

Comment: Edited to include this

Comment: Thanks everyone, probably confirming my thoughts but a massive help. Appreciate it.