# What should a Brand Guideline include?

Tags: branding, business

So I'm trying to form a mock business to practice branding, and I stumbled across this useful answer to a post [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12665/logo-pack-what-should-i-include).

If I'm going to have a folder on my pc with all the branding information for that company, what are all the files/information that I need for a full branding guideline, and not just a logo pack?

> Do I need to include an image with the exact colors in CMYK and RGB?
>
> Do I need to have different forms of the logo in different colors?
>
> What about logotype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branding guidelines documents can range from a couple of pages up to 50, 100 or even more pages in some cases, depending on the scale of the brand and so on. Better look at some examples and decide what you need and what you don't:

- [Google](https://www.behance.net/gallery/9028077/google-visual-assets-guidelines-part-1)
- [Facebook](https://en.facebookbrand.com/guidelines/brand)
- [Twitter](https://about.twitter.com/content/dam/about-twitter/company/brand-resources/en_us/Twitter_Brand_Guidelines_V2.0.pdf)
- [Argento](http://www.argentowine.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Argento-Brand-Logo-Guidelines-August-2013.pdf)
- [Jamie Oliver](https://issuu.com/joaodiogo/docs/frv-brand-guidelines-_final_)

For a basic guidelines presentation you should at least include:

- logo slide (safe area, spacing, variations, etc)
- typography slide (font families to be used)
- colors slide (main and secondary colors, where to use each)

Comment: how about for, say a clothing brand?

Comment: Now you're just adding details to your original question. Google something like "nike branding guidelines" or other brands, until you find something useful. Kind of the same situation basicly.